# Why are dyntopo and symmetry not in the viewfinder menu bar in sculpting mode? (screenshot)

Tags: sculpting

In all the sculpting tutorials I watch, dyntopo and symmetry are supposed to be in the top right corner of the viewport interface by default, but I don't have them (see picture). Any ideas why or how to add them there by default?

[image]

Comment: It looks like Blenderkit replaces it.. That's why... Is there a way to turn that behavior off?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a bug, check this [thread](https://developer.blender.org/T80066). but you can turn `dyntopo` and `mirror` on also in this menu: `Active Tool and Workspace Settings` icon:

[image]